# iPhone Music app: music with an iCloud status of Uploaded can't be played?

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud, apple-music, itunes-match

I have a PC (running Windows) with a collection of MP3 files I ripped from CD. I installed iTunes (12.7.0.166) and setup iCloud Music Library, and it went through the uploading/matching process on my files.

From my iPhone (iOS 11.0.3, and which has iCloud Music Library enabled), I can see all of my library in the Music App. However I noticed that some files would not play - a popup would appear saying "Item Not Available" and "This item can't be played".

I did a little digging in my library, and I found that I have this problem with files with an iCloud status of Uploaded. I can play files with a status of Matched just fine.

The files with a status of Uploaded are not available on Apple Music or the iTunes store - e.g. Turkish music from the 60s. So they will never become Matched. But, I should still be able to play them as an Apple Music or iTunes Match subscriber - that is supposed to be a selling point of iCloud Music Library.

Is there something wrong with my library (iTunes side or iPhone side) that is preventing these songs from playing? I have fewer than 100,000 songs, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out. What fixed it for me was plugging my iPhone into the computer with my iTunes library, and syncing. I had not done that since iTunes had finished uploading my collection.

It didn't seem to transfer any files (other than doing a backup), but after that, I could play all of my songs on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be in iTunes on your PC.

Since Apple Music couldn't find any matching, iTunes Match should automatically upload your song, only if they are matching the [specifications](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146). They are found in the section "About file formats"

Comment: They are matching the specifications, and they were uploaded. If they weren't, the status would be "Ineligible", not "Uploaded".